# Modify xml file using javascript in LocalHost

Tags: javascript, xml, xml-parsing

I have a XML file like this :

```
<solution>
  <cells>
    <cell></cell>
    <cell></cell>
    <cell></cell>
    .
    .
    .
  </cells>
</solution>
```

And I want to **fill each cell** of this **XML** file from a **HTML** file using javascript. and then send the XML file to the server for processing...

**Note :** these XML and HTML files are in my localHost.

How can I modify this XML file ? should I parse it? (How?) or should I use AJAX for getting responseXML of this document and then edit the DOM of that ?

Comment: Should i parse xml or an ajaxa request ?